# Вызывать JS функцию и записать в переменную

Tags: javascript, java, android

Возможно ли вызывать функцию, которая находится в html файле, который загружен в WebView и записать результат выполнения этой функции в java переменную?

Comment: Да, можно. Посмотрите тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4325639/android-calling-javascript-functions-in-webview

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

1. Напишите такой кастомный клиент:

   ```
   final class MyWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {
   @Override
   public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, JsResult result) {
       Log.d("LogTag", message);
       result.confirm();
       return true;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Прикрепите его к своему WebView:

   ```
   mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
   ```
3. Теперь грузите скрипт в WebView:

   ```
   webView.loadUrl("javascript:alert(functionThatReturnsSomething)");
   ```
4. Получите результат в onJsAlert message.

На практике не пробовал, но выглядит убедительно. Отпишитесь, получится ли.

Comment: Все работает, спасибо! Только там не setWebViewClient, а setWebChromeClient.